# google bigquery join each

Tags: google-bigquery, join

We are using the new feature "JOIN EACH" in google bigquery , and get the following error message :

```
Select             count( distinct  e.userid  )  , 
               avg(e.amount) , 
               e.country  
from         ( select userid,amount,country,ts from  [flat_table]
               where  event='E' ) as e  
              join    each   
             ( select userid,amount,country,ts from  [flat_table]
               where  event='B' ) as l    
              on   e.userid=l.userid 
  where       e.ts<=l.ts
  group  by   e.country;
```

**Query Failed
Error: Unknown field: usec**

The same query above worked correctly few days ago . What have been change ? Can you reccomend how to rewrite the above sqk correctly ? 
We cannot use "JOIN" , only "JOIN EACH" , because it's a self-join query of a huge table .

Thanks , H

Answer (score 0):

This is a query parsing / rewriting bug that we're actively working on to fix, and are looking into a workaround. The bug is related to dealing with nested records in the query. If there is a way to rewrite your query without referencing nested fields (note timestsamps have a nested structure, so you could use just the microsecond value instead), this may help.